# Permission denied after ugrading sonatype nexus

Tags: linux, permissions, debian, nexus, sonatype

I've `chown'd` the new files to the `nexus` user, and everything works flawlessly on the previous version, however when I try starting the new version (of course old version shut down).

**I receive "permission denied".**

Comment: can you add more details, like what commands you are running

Comment: `sudo chown nexus:nexus /opt/nexus-3.22.0-02/`
Editing service to point to the new directory
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl start nexus`
Get error on startup
`sudo systemctl status nexus` to see the error
Error: permission denied

Comment: I may be missing something, if you use sudo for the nexus commands arn't you using root?  Did you try it without sudo as the nexus user?

Comment: sudo starts the service, the actual starting is done by the nexus user.